# Use IWebHostEnvironment in Program.cs web host builder in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, and I need to access the `IWebHostEnvironment` in the `Program.cs` web host builder. This is what I have right now (`Program.cs`):

```cs
public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static bool IsDevelopment => 
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development";

    public static string HostPort => 
        IsDevelopment 
            ? "5000" 
            : Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls($"http://+:{HostPort}")
            .UseSerilog((context, config) => {
                config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Instead of doing the `IsDevelopment` check the way I do it, I would like to use the `IsDevelopment()` method from `IWebHostEnvironment`, not entirely sure how to do that. What I have right now works, but honestly it doesn't "feel right".

Comment: [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L155) is wrapper method which initializes features like  --- use Kestrel as the web server and configure it using the application's configuration providers,. If you see the implementation, it injects the hosting environment. If you want to have something similar then you refer the mentioned [code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L155).

Answer (score 11):

In .NET 6 you can use the new [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-startup-with-the-new-minimal-hosting-model).

In your main program, you can create an application builder and an application.  The `Environment` (as a `IWebHostEnvironment`) is available on both objects.

For example in `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var environment = builder.Environment;
```

Or:

```
var app = builder.Build();
var environment = app.Environment;
```

You may want to pass the environment to ConfigureServices like this:

```
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Environment);
```

*(PS: I don't think this code is dependent on using the minimal hosting model, but that makes it simpler.  I think the Environment properties are also available back to .NET 3.1 which is the original question.)*

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the `IWebHostingEnvironment` you should get it from the ***context*** parameter of `ConfigureAppConfiguration`

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    var isDev = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                    var isProd = context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction();
                    var envName = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```